# Android Notification FCM vs simple pull

Tags: android, performance, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

for my android app i need to receive some notifications from a server. The notifications are by no mean time critical and it would be enough to check for new notifications when the user opens the app, so no background activity at all.

I noticed, that it is recommended to use a service like FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) for any kind of notifications. However, I feel that I would introduce quite a big library for a very simple task with FCM, potentially causing worse battery life than just using simple sockets to ask the server for new notifications.

So I wonder if its better to use a service like FCM or just do simple pulling for notifications in my case.

Answer (score 5):

> I feel that I would intodruce quite a big libary for a very simple task with fcm, potentally causing worse battery life than just using simple sockets to ask the server for new notifications.

FCM uses one shared long-lived socket for all apps. There is a fat chance some other app on your phone is already using FCM, so having your app use the socket connection as well would not increase the battery usage at all.

> So I wonder if its better to use a service like fcm or just do simple pulling for notifications im my case.

Although your app does not require any background push messaging, I would still advise you to use FCM to inform the app of any events instead of asking the server every time you start the app. The general principle of polling versus eventing apply here. FCM is not difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Well as I know , **FCM** never force to run a background service to receive Push notification, you may simply adapt it in your project and its simple to use.

Even I saw in may sites that using FCM increases the users by sending them promotions and offers using push message.

You may read more at [**FCM**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)